# Problemas para decodificar un email pasado por un link

Tags: php, openssl

Me ha ocurrido que creía tener arreglado un problema y darme cuenta que no era así. A ver tengo una web que cuando se registra un usuario le mando un link a su correo para que cuando lo pinche se active su cuenta. Entonces con **openssl_encrypt** se lo encriptó y cuando pincha en el lo recibo mediante  POST. El problema viene al desencriptar, cuando recojo la cadena tipo "djphnihrfpvhpi=" y la mando a desencriptar me devuelve null.
Pongo código de como **sí** me funciona:

```
function desencriptar($valor,$method,$clave,$iv){ 
return  openssl_decrypt($valor, $method, $clave, false, $iv);  
} 

function encriptar($valor,$method,$clave,$iv){
return  openssl_encrypt($valor, $method, $clave, false, $iv);  
} 

$email = "CCCCCCCCC@DDD.ES";
$y = encriptar($email, METHOD_ENCRIPT[0], CLAVE_ENCRIPT[0], IV_ENCRIPT);

$z = desencriptar($y, METHOD_ENCRIPT[0], CLAVE_ENCRIPT[0], IV_ENCRIPT);
echo $z; //funciona
```

Ahora imaginar que recojo por POST el correo ya encriptado   y se lo asigno a una variable:

```
$y = "GQAGmUZjTauGYE7GF1Tz145ZZ2bD2b1TC33okzuwSIk="
```

Y se lo paso al mismo método de arriba pongo el código sin los métodos puesto que no los toco:

```
 $y = "GQAGmUZjTauGYE7GF1Tz145ZZ2bD2b1TC33okzuwSIk=";
 $z = desencriptar($y, METHOD_ENCRIPT[0], CLAVE_ENCRIPT[0], IV_ENCRIPT);
 echo $z; //No funciona
```

Pues me deja de funcionar. No se por que cuando asigno a una variable la cadena que se va a desencriptar me deja de funcionar.
Alguna idea por favor

Comment: Hola a todos investigando he probado con la función base64_encode y aunque funciona no lo veo seguro, ya que cuando llega el correo puedes ver el código fuente y copiar la parte encriptada copiarla y decodificarla tú mismo. Osea no lo veo nada seguro. Conocéis alguna  manera más segura para pasar el correo y id del usuario en la url

Comment: Hola carlos, lo que estas enviando basicamente es la variable `$y` que es equivalente a un "Token" para que le de click y rediriga (por ejemplo a) `/confirm_email?token=$y1`??

Comment: Si le envías un link al usuario registrado porque encriptarlo?? Yo por ejemplo me he registrado en lugares muy serios de la web y no encriptan nada, osea es al dueño del mail al que le llegara el link, que importa que en la url venga mi correo? Supongo que tendrás un token adicional para validar el registro, no veo muy claro porque encriptar el correo.

Comment: Hola @OCHOA, yo no lo hacía tampoco pero también es verdad que en muchos sitios viene encriptado. Y ahora que he intentado hacerlo y no lo consigo más quiero hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez y solo "Tal Vez", tengas mal configurado el script. Te dejo un ejemplo que según lo que he probado (colocando directamente el mail encriptado en una variable) funciona.

```
// <= Quitar esto para probar /*
$email = "CCCCCCCCC@DDD.ES";
echo "<br>Original String: " . $email;

// Store the cipher method
$ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";
// Use OpenSSl Encryption method
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
$options = 0;
// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for encryption
$encryption_iv = '1234567891011121';
// Store the encryption key
$encryption_key = "TuKey";

$encryption = openssl_encrypt($email, $ciphering,
            $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);

echo "<br>Encrypted String: " . $encryption . "\n";
// <= Quitar esto para probar */

// Prueba
/* <= Quitar esto para probar
$encryption = 'IBKFqI4KD0si27cZTp4V7w==';
$ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";
$options = 0;
Quitar esto para probar =>*/

// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for decryption
$decryption_iv = '1234567891011121';
// Store the decryption key
$decryption_key = "TuKey";
// Use openssl_decrypt() function to decrypt the data
$decryption=openssl_decrypt ($encryption, $ciphering,
        $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv);

echo "<br>Decrypted String: " . $decryption;
```

Comment: Hola @OCHOA no había visto tú respuesta. Si que te funciona, veo que has cambiado el formato de encriptar por "AES-128-CTR" pero he probado cambiarlo por "AES-256-CBC" y también funciona. La única diferencia más que veo es que has añadido un parámetro más "$encryption_key = "TuKey" . Este no lo tenía, ¿para que sirve?. Gracias

Comment: Básicamente es una clave para encriptar/desencriptar el texto y que refuerza el IV, es mas sin esa clave salta el error **Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended**. Prueba cambiando la clave de desencriptar por **TuKey2** y veras que el texto no se desencripta. Imagínate que es una llave publica de seguridad como las de MEGA u otros.

Comment: Gracias @OCHOA ya lo vi.